# C (or embedded script) function that will open a .txt file visually

Tags: c, file

I am writing a program that writes to a .txt file but with a separate function I would like to open the file visually (in the default text editor).

I want the function to do the same as double clicking a file...

Not opening a file just to edit it in the code (not with `fopen()`) but actually view the file in a separate window!

*Cross-Platform if possible.*

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{

system("exec programname filename");

return 0;
}
```

This works on linux, hope that helps. Im not quite sure how you could tell which editor is default and open that up though.

Comment: Environment variables `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR` could be used, in that order, with `vi` as the fallback if neither is set.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

If you were programming this hypothetical function in C on Windows, you could do something like

```
system ("notepad myfile.txt");
```

Comment: ok thanks for the help i should have mentioned this *edits main question* is there a way to do this cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this *cross-platform*.

If a user double-clicks on a file, then the OS takes over and checks to see which application has been associated with the file type. Since this is an OS specific activity, it differs in implementation from OS to OS.

To do it you would need to query the OS for the application to launch with a system call. This is OS-specific though.